# Spree 2.0.0 Combine 2 States during checkout?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, spree

Scenario:

I have removed the delivery step from Spree checkout process in my application and I'm able to complete the transaction successfully.

Issue:

When i navigate to "My account" page then "SHIPMENT STATE" column displays `nil` for the current order that was completed without "Delivery" state. I checked `Spree::Orders` table and it has `nil` value for "SHIPMENT STATE" for current order. It seems that "SHIPMENT STATE" is determined in "Delivery" state. According to my understanding when I removed "Delivery" state from checkout it created this issue. Any thoughts on this ? I have attached the screen shot of "My Account" page.

[image]

Question:

Is it possible to combine/render "Delivery" state view within "Payment" view during checkout. Even After removing (`remove_checkout_step :delivery`) delivery state from checkout?

Comment: There is no screenshot in your question.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Just attached.

Answer (score 0):

Spree does a number of things related to the transition to delivery. When we modify the state machine and remove that checkout step, these things still need to be done.

For reference, I'll point you to https://gist.github.com/Senjai/bb5a4c3cf0e0b77be92f#file-checkout-rb-L89-L93

```
if states[:delivery]
  before_transition :to => :delivery, :do => :create_proposed_shipments
  before_transition :to => :delivery, :do => :ensure_available_shipping_rates
  before_transition :from => :delivery, :do => :apply_free_shipping_promotions
end
```

When you remove the delivery step, create_proposed_shipments and friends do not occur.

Instead you can class_eval Spree::Order instead of the checkout controller.

Within a state_machine do block, you can add events that were highlighted to a different action. In this case, without delivery you would either want these actions on an after or to transition from payment (I haven't looked too deeply into it)

There may be extra work involved as you may have to set the shipping method/rate yourself. Because the view does this in vanilla spree. Again, it can be attached to the state machine.

See https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine for more information about state machines.

Answer (score -1):

I just completed this by doing following.

If you removed "Delivery" state and you want its view to be rendered in "payment" screen do following.

Step 1: Go to "payment" partial and add following lines where you want to show "delivery" screen.

```
<div>
<% @order.state = "delivery" %>
<%= render @order.state, :form => form %>
</div>
```

Step 2: This step resolves Shipment_State issue that prompts as blank for orders when "Delivery" state is removed form checkout process.

Go to app/controllers/checkout_controller_decorator.rb and paste following code.

```
Spree::CheckoutController.class_eval do

def before_payment
before_delivery
if @order.checkout_steps.include? "delivery"
  packages = @order.shipments.map { |s| s.to_package }
  @differentiator = Spree::Stock::Differentiator.new(@order, packages)
  @differentiator.missing.each do |variant, quantity|
  @order.contents.remove(variant, quantity)
  end
end
end
end
```

This method can be applied to any screen combination.
Looking forward towards spree community about their thoughts. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.